# Help getting processInstance value

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, class

I want to insert this Approval History section on opportunity to my PDF (There`s a pdf button on my opportunity object)..

[image]

But what appeared on my pdf
[[image]

Issue :

1. How to get every status date?
2. You can see there`s different "assign to" actor on approval history and pdf. how do i get the right actor?
3. how to split the value so it will appear in single row?

this is my vf

```
<div style="">
        <div Style="margin-top:15%; "  ><p Style="font-size:18px;" ><b>
            Approval History
            </b>
            </p>
            <table class="body" style = "text-align: center;font-size:14px; spacing:-1px; border:solid 1px black; ">
            <th style="width:10%; border:solid 1px black;">Date</th>
            <th style="width:6%; border:solid 1px black;">Status</th>
            <th style="width:10%; border:solid 1px black;">Assign To</th>
            <th style="width:10%; border:solid 1px black;">Actual Approver</th>
            <th style="width:15%; border:solid 1px black;">Comments</th>
            <th style="width:10%; border:solid 1px black;">Overall Status</th>


                <tr style="">
                    <td style = " width:10%; text-align:center; font-size:14px; spacing:-1px; border:solid 1px black;">
                        <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunity.ProcessInstances}" var="piValue">
                        <apex:column value="{!piValue.CompletedDate}" />
                        </apex:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td style = " width:10%; text-align:center; font-size:14px; spacing:-1px; border:solid 1px black;">
                        <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunity.ProcessSteps}" var="stepsValue">
                        <apex:column value="{!stepsValue.StepStatus}" />
                        </apex:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td style = " width:10%; text-align:center;font-size:14px; spacing:-1px; border:solid 1px black;">
                        <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunity.ProcessSteps  }" var="stepsValue">
                        <apex:column value="{!stepsValue.Actor.Name}" />
                        </apex:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td style = " width:10%; text-align:center;font-size:14px; spacing:-1px; border:solid 1px black;">
                        <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunity.ProcessSteps  }" var="stepsValue">
                        <apex:column value="{!stepsValue.Actor.Name}" />
                        </apex:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td style = " width:10%; text-align:center;font-size:14px; spacing:-1px; border:solid 1px black;">
                        <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunity.ProcessSteps}" var="stepsValue">
                        <apex:column value="{!stepsValue.Comments}" />
                        </apex:dataTable>
                    </td>
                    <td style = " width:10%; text-align:center; font-size:14px; spacing:-1px; border:solid 1px black;">
                        <apex:dataTable value="{!Opportunity.ProcessInstances}" var="piValue">
                        <apex:column value="{!piValue.Status}" />
                        </apex:dataTable>
                    </td>
                </tr>    

           </table>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're having is your `Date` is defined as using `<apex:column value="{!piValue.CompletedDate}" />`. If you look at the [Object Reference for ProcessInstance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm) The Start Date for ProcessInstance isn't an available field for you to query on. That would be something you'd need to calculate in your controller using the `CompletedDate.addseconds(-ElapsedTimeInMinutes)` to "back into" to the value of the `StartDate`.

You'd then need to either:

- Create an AggregrateResult field for `Date` that combined both `CalculatedStartDate` and `CompletedDate` so the records could be brought down properly from your controller.
- Replace the null values for the CompletedDates associated with the Statuses you're trying to match the StartDates with that are missing in your table which are likely returned in a query in the controller.